# What's the general range of a 3DS XL Wi-Fi antenna?

Tags: streetpass, nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I'm having fun using Streetpass, and want to work out a daily route that will maximise the amount of exposure that I get via the Wifi Streetpass feature. ([Gamification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification) is a hell of a thing)

Say I'm standing in an open field (replace *Open* with Packed-like-Sardines, and *Field* with Central Station in Sydney, Australia). What sort of effective range does my 3DS XL boast? I imagine that (even in ideal situations) that it can't exceed 50-60 meters. Is this the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the specifications in the [manual](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/downloads/CTR_ops_eng.pdf), the recommended wireless distance is within 98 ft (30 m), in perfect circumstances, and "depending on surrounding conditions this distance may be less".

if this is indeed speaking of the wireless technology used for things like StreetPass and the like, then you have quite the range, but the specs are unclear what exactly the wireless distance is referring to (whether it is for wifi connection, or for StreetPass.)

Comment: I imagine that this would be the case, as it's using the wifi antenna for Streetpass. thanks!